# retrieving XMLHttpRequest parameters in python

Tags: python, ajax, cgi

Client-side code submits an object (in the POST request body) or query string (if using GET method) via ajax request to a python cgi script. Please note that the object/query string parameters are **not** coming from a

```
<form> or <isindex>.
```

How can I retrieve these parameters from within the server-side python script using standard library modules (e.g., cgi)?

Thanks very much

**EDIT:**
*@codeape*: Thanks, but wouldn't that work only for submitted **forms**? In my case, no form is being submitted, just an asynchronous request.
 Using your script, len(f.keys()) returns 0 if no form is submitted! I can probably recast the request as a form submission, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

You use the cgi.FieldStorage class. Example CGI script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgi
from os import environ
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type: text/plain"
print
print "REQUEST_METHOD:", environ["REQUEST_METHOD"]
print "Values:"
f = cgi.FieldStorage()
for k in f.keys():
    print "%s: %s" % (k, f.getfirst(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

codeape already answered on this. Just for the record, please understand that how the HTTP request is emitted is totally orthogonal - what the server get is an HTTP request, period.

Answer (score 0):

*@codeape* , *@bruno desthuilliers*:

Indeed, cgi.FieldStorage() retrieves the parameters. The output I was getting earlier was apparently due to my passing the parameters as a string (JSON.stringify() object) in the body of the request -- rather than as key-value pairs.
Thanks